# How do you calc the mean along an axis of numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, mean

*I am new to python.*

Here is my three dimensional array:

```
my_data=numpy.zeros((index1,index2,index3))
```

For illustration, let's say the sizes are:

```
index1 = 5
index2 = 4
index3 = 100
```

I want to compute the mean of all index3 values for a given index2 value.

I tried various options:

```
# Does not work
result[index1][index2] = numpy.mean(my_data[index1][index2][index3], axis=2)

# Also does not work
result = numpy.zeros((index1, index2))
result[index1][index2] = numpy.mean(my_data[index1][index2])
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share the error that you are getting?

Comment: items *= arr.shape[ax]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Indices need to be accessed between 0 and [the size of your array]-1. i.e. if you need to access the last element of an array of size 100 (such as your third index), you need to use `arr[99]`. So, in your question, try using `my_data[index1-1][index2-1][index3-1]`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `np.mean()` with the `axis` keyword:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

data = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(3,3,3))
```

Yields:

```
[[[4 0 3]
  [3 3 1]
  [3 2 4]]

 [[0 0 4]
  [2 1 0]
  [1 1 0]]

 [[1 4 3]
  [0 3 0]
  [2 3 0]]]
```

Then apply:

```
np.mean(data,axis=1)

#Or data.mean(axis=1)
```

Returns:

```
[[3.33333333 1.66666667 2.66666667]
 [1.         0.66666667 1.33333333]
 [1.         3.33333333 1.        ]]
```

Comment: It worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   Thank-you :-)